# Does deleting iCloud photos affect them on devices?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

If I delete a photo from my iCloud will it also be removed from my devices that are connected to my account?

Comment: I think it would, if you use iCloud photo library. But it should also prompt you to warn you about that (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a good way to clear out space in iCloud.They don't delete immediately, you can recover recently deleted files for a while, but they do disappear from connected devices and will eventually be deleted - any copies you export onto your computer (outside of the Photos app) will not be affected.  I back up older photos from the Photos app, by exporting them to a folder on my Mac, then removing them from iCloud, to recover space when my 5 GB of free storage gets full.