# Synchronize deleting photos from iCloud to iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I [know](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104925/deleting-photos-on-the-phone-does-it-affect-them-on-icloud) that deleting photos from iCloud Photos does not remove them from iPhone. But what should I do to synchronize deleting? I want to leave on iPhone only those photos, that I have in my iCloud Photos

Comment: The answers to the question you've linked don't apply if you use iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: I don't know what it was, but after resynchronize it starts work. So, you right, all works as in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242255/does-deleting-icloud-photos-affect-them-on-devices) answer